# My wife and my, or I?

Tags: grammar

I understand that one should use me or I the same as they would with out the other person in the sentence. My questions is however, is the sentence "they fixed my wife and I's car" correct? My wife and my car?

Comment: "I's" is essentially never correct. See the questions I linked to in the following post: [Can we switch to a better canonical question about using pronouns in compound possessives?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7109)

Answer (score 0):

The form of each owner should be the same. So you could say:

> The car belonging to *me and my wife*....
>
> *My wife and I* own a car.
>
> *My wife's and my* car...

The trick to this is to remove the other person to see if it still works.

> The car belonging to *me*... The car belonging to *my wife*...
>
> *My wife* owns a car... *I* own a car...
>
> *My wife's* car... *My* car...

As a general rule, the other name comes before the "I/my" in the sentence, but after the "me" in the sentence. But, at that point, it's more of a stylistic choice.

[Source](http://www.elearnenglishlanguage.com/blog/english-mistakes/i-vs-me/) (just Google "I vs. me" for more info)